# No output from exec when using tclsh inside shell script

Tags: exec, sh, tclsh

I have a weird situation here. I need to run exec on a script, getValue.itcl, but I am getting no output if i try to run it inline with input redirection. Sorry if i am using the wrong terms.

Using it inline helps with other aspects of this script, otherwise i would need to separate pieces. And I am using tcl 8.0 (no option on that).

Example:
This works when I use a shell script that restarts as tclsh.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

# \
cd 'dirname $0'
# Next line restarts as tclsh \
exec tclsh 'basename $0' $*

proc Main { } {
    set val [exec getValue.itcl PARAMETER]
    puts "$val"
}
Main
exit
```

But if i run this a different way in a script, it will not work.

This does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

tclsh << EOSCRIPT

    set val [exec getValue.itcl PARAMETER]
    puts "$val"
EOSCRIPT

exit 0
```

I'll get no output, i don't see what the difference is between using tclsh in the first method as opposed to the second when it comes to simply executing a command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, stupid mistake.

Using << is called a here document...heredoc?

I have used them a little in the past but not much, i dug up an older example and realized that variables are expanded before being sent in. I have to escape them.

This works:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

tclsh << EOSCRIPT

    set val [exec getValue.itcl PARAMETER]
    puts "\$val"
EOSCRIPT

exit 0
```